# add delete row button on handstable

Tags: handsontable

is it possible to add the button in handsontable column which will  delete a row  when click particular button?

Comment: do you want the button to be placed in a column or outside of the table?

Comment: want to add row delete button in column.

Comment: what have you tried? when you say place the button on a column, do you mean on every cell of a column?

Comment: yes every cell of a column

Answer (score 1):

Use the removeRowPlugin : add this library :

```
<script src="http://docs.handsontable.com/0.17.0/scripts/removeRow-demo/handsontable.removeRow.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://docs.handsontable.com/0.17.0/scripts/removeRow-demo/handsontable.removeRow.css">
```

and add : `removeRowPlugin: true,`

http://docs.handsontable.com/0.17.0/demo-custom-buttons.html

Comment: That link is now dead.